# Laravel 5.6. Cant get error message in constructor

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get validator error message after it failed, but unsuccessfully. I have this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Validators\Common;

use App\Model\Contracts\AbstractClasses\Validator as BaseValidator;
use App\Model\Contracts\Interfaces\Validators\Common\ConversationMessageValidatorInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ConversationMessageValidator extends BaseValidator implements ConversationMessageValidatorInterface
{

    /**
     * Validates message sending.
     * @param mixed $data
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function validateCreate($data)
    {

        $this->validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);     
        $this->validator->fails();
        dd($this->validator->errors()->first());

    }  

}

<?php 

namespace App\Model\Contracts\AbstractClasses;

use App\Model\Contracts\Interfaces\Validators\Common\ValidatorInterface;

class Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{

    protected $validator;

    /**
     * Returns validator object.
     * @return mixed
     */ 
    public function getValidator()
    {

        return $this->validator;

    }

    /**
     * Returns validation errors.
     * @return mixed
     */ 
    public function getErrors()
    {

        return $this->getValidator()->errors();

    }   

}
```

it dumps this message: "validation.required", even tough I have pretty much the same code in my previous project which works as I expect:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Validators\PresentationalSubsystem;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Model\Contracts\AbstractClasses\Validator as AbstractValidator;
use App\Model\Contracts\Interfaces\Validators\PresentationalSubsystem\ForumThreadValidatorInterface;

class ForumThreadValidator extends AbstractValidator implements ForumThreadValidatorInterface
{

    public function validateThread($data)
    {

        $this->validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'content' => 'required|string|min:1',
            'description' => 'required|string|min:1',
            'title' => 'required|string|min:1',
            'forum_id' => 'required|exists:forums,id'
        ]);

        $this->validator->fails();
        print_r($this->validator->errors()->first());

    }

}
```

And this prints out: The content field is required.

My question would be: why my first code does not print error message? instead it prints validation rule that fails. How to change that?

EDIT:
validateCreate is called here:

```
   public function sendMessage($account, $data)
    {

        if(!$this->conversationMessageValidator->validateCreate($data)) {
            return $this->conversationMessageFormatter->prepareCreateResponseWithErrors($this->conversationMessageValidator->getErrors());
        }
}
```

and this function is called from constructor:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request, $conversationId)
{

    $request->merge(['conversation_id' => $conversationId]);
    return $this->conversationService->sendMessage(Auth::user(), $request->all());

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling `validateCreate`?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. resources/lang/validation.php file was removed accidentally some time before, thats why instead of messages it was returning the actual path to translation of it. I always thought that it is an error code, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $messages = [];
    foreach ($validator->messages()->getMessages() as $field_name => $message){
         $messages[] = $message[0];
     }
    dd($messages);

}
```

Comment: It returns .array:1 [
  0 => "validation.required"
]. Still only validation rule not actual message

Comment: you want what validation you have given is it ?

Comment: I want to get actual error message not the rule that failed. Because now It returns validation.required, thats the rule that failed, but I want to get actual error message " Message is required" for example, and display that to user.